# Drupal Fatal error: Call to undefined function views_get_enabled_views()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I use drupal 7.22 with Apache 2.2 , mysql 5.5 and PHP 5.3.

I'm having the error of WSOD, and when I enable the error message, it shows:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function views_get_enabled_views() in
>   /var/www/drupal7/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.map.inc on
>   line 150

It happens when I migrate the whole drupal to another system, or when I update the core to the recent released version, WHERE I enter the username and password to access the administration page ( /drupal-address/user).

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because of view does not support some function of new drupal 
check last reply on this link
https://drupal.org/node/1778470
Also 
https://drupal.org/node/1170192

Comment: I can not really understand this: https://drupal.org/node/1170192. Would you please tell me what's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: this function does not supported by drupal this version , you can apply patch from this link  https://drupal.org/node/1170192